# Angular. Initiation new angular directive after AJAX request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

Help me, please.
I have some JS code, that allow work with LEAFLET map.
https://gist.github.com/russtanevich/140235d5456c3215df6ac8b788485ad0

[image]

The APP allow to add on map new adverts and when we click on marker - we see information about  advert.
We can choose some category or contain some works in text of advert as filter. All filters works through ajax request (lines 51-81). Various ajax requests for various type of filter.
After AJAX request we change $scope.mapMarkers (line 13, 54, 61 etc.). OK.
mapMarkers is variable that contain array of marker objects (as line 86). okey. marker object has a popup message (as we can see on the picture). This message is angular directive (line 96, line 5).

Markers that we get after the first load application have a good popup message (angular directive initiate).
Markers that we get after filter AJAX request - also have popup message as angular directive. But it is logically - they don't show. We have empty popup message, because angular directive doesn't initiate in this occasion.

[image]

I hope, we understood me. Maybe I explained bad way.
What is my mistake? Architecture? Or maybe is there solution?

Thank you very much! Have a nice day! Best regards!

Comment: I did not understand the problem. You mean your popups dont initiate. is that the problem. Could you be more specific as too what are you trying to solve?

Comment: A lot of the problem is the fact that you are mixing in jQuery wit AngularJS. Decide if you want to implement this with Angular or not. If so, avoid using jQuery to manipulate the DOM.

Comment: @Sudakatux yes. When I apply filter query var $scope.mapMarkers get a new array. Attribute "message" of marker object is the angular directive. New markers (after filtering) also have attribute "message"(they are angular directives too). And popup in new markers is empty. Because angular directive doesn't initiate. Yes. It is my problem. I don't have empty popup message after filtering(via ajax). I want to find solution how to force to initiate ng-directives after full complition html and js code (after next ajax request)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i havent look at the module 'leaflet-directive' but this is how I handled it on a similar app. I created a directive

```
app.directive('theDirective', function($compile, $timeout){
  return {
    restrict:'E',
    templateUrl: 'template.html' 
  };
});
```

in my case im using templateUrl which im initiating elsewhere with `<script>` like tags that part will resemble what you tried to do in `geodataToMarkers` only that  the way you wrote the template will not work because angular cant tell its a template.

Now when you add a marker you need to populate your template with stuff in your model meaning you got to tie them together. you can do that
by injecting the `$compile` to a method and tie both things together

```
 $compile(domElem)($scope);
```

That will fill your directive with the model. *note* that you should pass domHtml the directive not the html meaning `<the-directive></the-directive>`

It is kind of hard to explain with your code because you are mixing jquery and angular a whole lot and you have to change many things. but to be clear on a possible quick solution

on the marker you have to put a div with an id='yourmarker' when you want to put stuff together, just look for the the element with that id

```
 var domElem = document.getElementById(markerPointerId);
          domElem.innerHTML = '<the-directive></the-directive>';
```

insert your directive. and compile it

```
$compile(domElem)($scope);
```

you should see you marker populated with the scope you have put in.
This by al means aint the Angular way. im just giving you a solution that i know works

Hope it helps.